# Is there a way to set something up, like a Vagrant, but that installs on computers?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

Sort of like modifying the install image for Ubuntu.
On my Ubuntu installations, I like to have the same setup, and setting that all up is cumbersome.

Stuff like:

- rvm
- ruby
- Gnome 3
- Chrome
- Atom Editor
- a bunch of custom bash scripts that I wrote
- my .bash_profile

etc.

So, is there a way to create or modify the install process such that all of that is installed for me?

Comment: http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/news/build-your-own-distro-part-one

Comment: oooo. I'll give that a go when I get home

Comment: looks like remastersys is no longer in development or available for download

Comment: I was wrong, here is a updated tool that does the same http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-live-system-iso-for-your-ubuntu-based-linux-machines-using-systemback/